# Monioring the performance of asp.net web application using IIS log files

Tags: performance, iis-7, monitoring, logparser, iis-logs

I have IIS log files, I need to findout the errors generated by the asp.net web application which are hosted by IIS 7.
I used Log parser to paarse IIS log files, but I want to find errors such as timeout errors ,session errors and other 500x errors occured in the web application hosted in the server, only by analysing IIS logs.
I'm puzzled about which feild in IIS logs i need to look upon ? I have only IIS log files and no access to Event viewer.
What are the necessary feild i can parse in IIS logs to indicate that the application has undergone some error due to heavy load,or server is taking too long to respond?
How can i use 'timetaken' or any other feild in feild in IIS logs to say that the web application is lagging inperformance and prone to errors by analysing the previous IIS log files.

I'm a newbie to this.Pls help.

Comment: have you tried this - http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/performance-issues/troubleshooting-iis-performance-issues-or-application-errors-using-logparser ?

Comment: @swazza85 Thanks. I used log parser to parse the logs but this link helped me a lot . The whole idea is to  parse the log files to improve the performace of the application .. I got all the results such as no.of hits the error code 400x,500x error code has happened. Is there a way to improve the performace of the application by parsing the log files.. I got all the results but noidea to proceed forward with that!! I'll accept this as answer.Post this as a sol.

Comment: so you have the results now - what you are asking is how to act on those results? i.e. how do you go about tuning your application? is that what you are asking?

Comment: @swazza85 Yes. for eg. after analysis there was a page which got 302 ,401 couple of times . at a specific time say 9:00 am the error count (400x and 500x ) are more.. so how to solve this. I checked the application it was working fine.. is there a way i can solve this in server side.